Flutter flutter_local_notifications Package - can it check online status?
My apps currently use Firebase Push Notifications. The message is created from another server. Once the mesasge is created it is sent out using Firebase.
But can I do this without using Firebase? Because technically I could create a restful API which returns a list of daily messages along with the time in which they are supposed to go out.
I was looking at flutter_local_notificatons package and I can see that I can schedule a notification. But when that schedule is run, is it possible for it to first call my  external restful api and check if there are any messages it needs to send?  If so I don't need to use Firebase anymore.

Technically yes it can , but there are some challenges you may face , for example : the device is experience network issue(so you need to handle that case) , also in some cases the OS it self restrict network activity(From my experience you need to get permission for background activity) , also in general you need your notification to deal with api request in less than 30 sec and the frequency of that notification daily to be as low as possible for your use case (in my case it was every 6 hours) otherwise the os will restrict it.
On the other hand Firebase notification guarantee the delivery of the message even if the mobile has no internet connection in that time

Thanks for the reply. Interesting. For IOS background activity is in the options in xcode. My API would be really quick (<1 sec) and in general I don't think any apps would push more than twice in one day, although some of them are based on weather (snowfall, ski areas etc) so that might be a challenge.
